# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.?

Tags: magento2

I'm getting the error "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page." whenever I click on buy on a product, and I've tried to increase the amount of max_input_vars in my php.ini file to 100000 but it didn't work. Does anyone know why this happens in magento 2?

Comment: are you on localhost ?

Comment: I'm on a server